# Weird gap in front of cursor in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am getting a weird gap in my PhpStorm installation as displayed in the GIF. I have another installation for IntelliJ and it also mimics the same behaviour.

[image]

I'm on OS X El Capitan and the PhpStorm version is as below:

```
PhpStorm 2016.1.2
Build #PS-145.1616, built on May 24, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b198 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Comment: 1) Try different font 2) Try different (not bundled) JDK

Comment: what editor font do you use?

Comment: I was using Darcula theme with some customisations. Going back to default Darcula seems to have fixed it. Leaving the question open just in case someone has an answer of what exactly was causing that.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I used to have the same problem. I had the exact same settings on another computer with a larger screen, and that one works fine. Then I just simply change the font-size to be smaller, **better to be even number**, Now it works fine again. Not sure if this is the solution, but you can try it.